# bash read a character from every string in file

Tags: string, bash, variables

I have not so easy task and I am in need of useful advice.

I have a file, containing list of hosts:

```
host1.example.domain.com
host2.example.domain.com
host3.example.domain.com
```

and a variable in a bash script, containing all possible hosts:

```
hostblabla.newdomain.org
...
host3.example.domain.com
```

What I need is to make simple regexp that mathes only that hosts that are present in my first list.
I think about it this way:

1. read the first character of all strings in my first list
2. check if all charaters are the same
3. if they are, add this character to regexp
4. else make `regxep = $regexp"*"`
5. check regexp with my variable that contains all hosts

But I have little expirience in Bash and I have no idea how can I read only one character from EACH string in bash?

I know that I can do the following:

```
first_character=${a: :1}
```

but this is only first charater from a whole variable $a.

Comment: Why do you have it as a variable in the script and not as an external file?

Comment: it does not matter, i can write it out to file, if it is important, but i guess no.

Answer (score 3):

So you need an intersections of two list, is that right?

put both lists sorted with unique lines into files:

```
sort -u original_list_of_hosts.txt > sorted_list_of_hosts.txt
echo "$POSSIBLE_HOSTS" | sort -u > possible_hosts.txt
```

and then use `join` command to take common part of both files:

```
join sorted_list_of_hosts.txt possible_hosts.txt
```

It will output sorted list of hosts which exists in both list.

Comment: This can be expressed as a one-liner using process substitution -- `join <(sort -u hostfile.txt) <(echo "$POSSIBLE_HOST" | sort -u)`

Comment: @ShawnChin: Yes, I know. I wanted to keep it easy to understand. In real world I would use it as you propose, to avoid temporary files. +1

Comment: No, unfortunately no. Because I have all 
    host1.example.domain.com
    host2.example.domain.com
    host3.example.domain.com
in my second list. So intersection of both list will be same as the first one. 
The idea to use join is very good indeed. But not in my case, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Using grep:

```
#!/bin/bash
s[0]="hostblabla.newdomain.org"
s[1]="host3.example.domain.com"
regex=""
for h in ${s[@]}; do
    regex="$regex -e $h "
done
grep $regex input
```

Comment: I was thinking right like that, but how can I transform my file containing list of required hosts into an array `s` ?
for i in file; do
    ???